# How can I get a WSL linux path from cmd.exe?

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I often need to know WSL mounted path names from Windows.
I have now seen many sketch solutions to the problem so I thought I should share MY WAY.

Use cases for this might be running a linux tool against something running from cmd.exe or gdb debugging something from a windows development environment.

As in:
"C:\Windows\System32"="/mnt/c/Windows/System32"

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %G in ('bash -c "wslpath -a -u '%APPDATA%'"') do @echo %G` (supply any valid Windows path instead of `%APPDATA%`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I figured out..
The following line will pull the CWD aka %CD% and put it in a variable called LNX_PATH

```
    for /f %p in ('bash.exe -c "pwd"') do set LNX_PATH=%p
```

Here is a simplified batch file example that will use vi to open a text file called 'test.txt' from your Windows Documents directory.

```
@echo off

:: This is the path to the file I want to launch using vi...
Set WIN_DOC_PATH=%UserProfile%\Documents

:: Switch to that path, get the CWD (linux style) and switch back
pushd "%WIN_DOC_PATH%"
    for /f %%n in ('bash.exe -c "pwd"') do set LNX_DOC_PATH=%%n
popd

:: Launch vi (via bash) using the correct path format
bash.exe -c "vi %LNX_DOC_PATH%/test.txt"
```

When this batch exits, you will be back at cmd.exe right where you started.

If someone has a better (non sketchy) way to get this path, I would love to know it!

Comment: Ahh.. there is a tool called wslpath that will do similar things.